# How to group JSON data on the base of attribute value in different variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to group JSON data by color as an example:

- `blue` colors will be collected in variable `"a"`
- `green` colors will be collected in variable `"b"`
- `red` colors will be collected in variable `"c"`

**How can I do that, My JSON data is here:**

```js
var data = [{
    "name": "2",
    "number": "222",
    "day": 20,
    "color": "red"
},  
{
    "name": "3",
    "number": "333",
    "day": 19,
    "color": "green"
}, 
{
    "name": "5",
    "number": "333",
    "day": 19,
    "color": "blue"
}];

console.log(data.reduce(function(result, current) {
    result[current.color] = result[current.color] || [];
    result[current.color].push(current);
    return result;
}, {}));
```

consequently, all blue, green, and red values ​​in the data are collected in different variables in series.

Comment: Explain the result you expect and show us what you've tried.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You need to show a bit more effort. Research, go read up on stuff, _try something_. Rule of thumb: If your question boils down to a mere “how can I do dat”, it probably does not really belong here in the first place.

Comment: @User156771, added code snippet and updated question presentation, you have to learn [How to Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in reduce, you must grouping item by color, and then set variable a,b,c:

```
const reducedData = data.reduce((acc, rec) => {
  if (acc.hasOwnProperty(rec.color)){
    acc[rec.color].push(rec)
  }
  else {
    acc = {...acc, [rec.color]: [rec]}
  }
  return {...acc}
},{})

const a = reducedData.blue
const b = reducedData.green
const c = reducedData.red
```

See full example in playground: https://jscomplete.com/playground/s507178